# Update mongo document inside the find result function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Can anyone tell me if this is a legit in mongoose. I'm trying to update a sub doc within an array of student main doc. When I run the update query from shell it works fine, but from the code below it is not updating the data.

```
     Student.findOne({
    "phone._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId('587e6409e06170ba1708dc21')
},
{
    _id: 0,
    phone: 1
},
function(err,
phone){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }if(phone.Home==phone.Cell||phone.secondary===undefined){
        Student.update({
            'Student._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId('587e6409e06170ba1708dc22'),
            'phone._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId('587e6409e06170ba1708dc21')
        },
        {
            "$set": {
                'phone.$.number': 453454554
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as per documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/
db.collection takes several arguments

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>
   }
)
```

so you should do something like this:

```
Student.update({
    'Student._id' : ObjectId('587e6409e06170ba1708dc22'),
    <Your Query>, 
    true, 
    true
})
```

Comment: Hi argoden, my question is that whether I can write an update inside the findOne({"phone._id":mongoose.Types.ObjectId('587e6409e06170ba1708dc21') },{_id:0,phone:1}, function(err,     phone) { //update logic }), I've also tried resolving the promise from findOne that didn't help either.

Comment: i don't think you can. you can use what findOne returns in update query, but i don't think you can use it inside.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you can do this:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   <filter>,
   <update>,
   {
     projection: <document>,
     sort: <document>,
     maxTimeMS: <number>,
     upsert: <boolean>,
     returnNewDocument: <boolean>
   }
)
```

Comment: please look at my edited question i've added 'if' condition, how can I achieve that using findOneAndUpdate as I've to compare two different fields in the same document. Any suggestion or help is much appreciated.